# unconvert community wiki for 4.5-year-old question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480373)?

Tags: support, status-completed, community-wiki

Per the latest [community wiki rule change](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki), [Generic Inherited ViewPage<> and new Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480373/generic-inherited-viewpage-and-new-property) seems like a good candidate for converting from community wiki back to a normal question.

- 20 of 22 total edits by the OP (the community edits were fixing minor typos I think)
- 34 upvotes, favorited 21 times
- *[selfish reason]* I remember spending many hours on my answer back in 2009, and since then the answer got 53 upvotes. It was a fun problem to solve and I don't mind too much, but I've always been a bit wistful for the lost rep. ;-)

Comment: Completed.  This seems like a good use case for a moderator flag, rather than a full-blown meta post.

Comment: Great, thanks Robert. I didn't know that flagging was used for anything other than inappropriate/offensive content. Now I know better. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing: will the asker and answerers get rep for existing upvotes to questions converted from community wiki to normal questions?  Or only for new upvotes?

Comment: Only for new upvotes.