# Guidelines for when a community wiki can be converted to a normal Q&A

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

**What is the criteria for removing the Wiki status from a question?**

I understand that only moderators can convert questions to and from [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) mode. I would like to know the criteria moderators have for doing so, or if it really is just [up to each individual moderator's discretion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83373/284743). This would help me know whether or not to flag CW questions in the future.

In the past, a post could be automatically converted into a CW after a certain number of edits, but [this is no longer so](http://stackoverflow.blog/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/). Thus I know of at least [one example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252381/unconvert-community-wiki-for-4-5-year-old-question-http-stackoverflow-com-que) where such [a post was unconverted by a moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1480373/revisions).

**Specific example**

The reason that this came up was that I flagged [this CW question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-do-i-display-an-alert-dialog-on-android) to see if it could be unconverted. I don't especially mind that my flag was declined, but I would like more guidelines for when a flag might be accepted.

My thinking was

- The existing answers are mostly code snippets with very little explanation.
- I would like to add a more canonical answer.
- Although Community Wiki [theoretically](http://stackoverflow.blog/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/) allows the community to create canonical answers, it hasn't happened in the 6 years of this Q&A's existence.
- I could create the canonical answer myself anyway, but I am not motivated to spend an hour or two doing so because I won't get any imaginary internet points for my work. This is built into the gaming philosophy of the system.
- Documentation is in some sense replacing what community wiki originally intended. So the need for this question in particular (and many other questions in general) to be CW is not as critical as it was in the past.

However, some point for keeping the status quo could be

- The existing posts, while not as complete as I would like to see, are adequate enough to help many people.
- It was the question author themself who made the post CW.

**Update**

I'm willing to admit that all of my original reasons for un-CW'ing the question I mentioned are poor. However, that was just an example. My question here is more general. *What are valid reasons that a community wiki could be turned into a normal Q&A?*

[This question and it's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288020/how-to-decide-whether-to-un-wiki-questions-answers-posted-in-rep-denial-era) provide some useful insights. One thing that is missing, though, is if it is ever OK to un-CW posts that were made CW by their authors.

Comment: Why should the post be un-cw'd? It seems to be fairing well of its own accord. I'm not saying it should stay that way, I'm just not seeing a reason for it not to.

Comment: @TinyGiant, It's certainly not bad. I had originally wanted to add what I thought would be a better and more canonical answer, but I probably won't if it remains CW. My question here is to ask for more specific criteria than "it seems to be fairing well".

Comment: Sorry, missed that part, possibly could use some emphasis. While it may be slightly disappointing that you would be less willing to contribute to the usefulness of Stack Overflow simply because you won't get paid for it in imaginary internet points, it is definitely an understandable position.

Comment: None of the 5 reasons you provided to un-CW the question are particularly good reasons... 4 really shouldn't matter, for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decide whether to un-wiki questions/answers posted in rep-denial era](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288020/how-to-decide-whether-to-un-wiki-questions-answers-posted-in-rep-denial-era)

Comment: @gnat, this does provide more insight into the issue. I had missed that question in my search. It is very similar to my question, though it doesn't deal with the situation of questions that were made CW by the OP.

Comment: [This blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) seems to state that canonicals *should* be community wikis

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I see any reason to un-CW that particular post, especially given the impetus that it was the OP that decided to make it a community wiki to begin with.

To your rationale...

> The existing answers are mostly code snippets with very little explanation.

Yes, this is a problem.  You can downvote those liberally since CW posts don't impact your reputation, and if you feel like they don't really help, there's nothing really stopping you from downvoting them.

> I would like to add a more canonical answer.

<s>Nothing's stopping you from doing that on this question.</s>

> Although Community Wiki theoretically allows the community to create canonical answers, it hasn't happened in the 6 years of this Q&A's existence.

This is more of a philosophical debate about community wikis and not entirely germane to this post.  It's the case that non-CW posts are routinely canonical, but there's nothing written that says that a CW post which *acts* like a canonical has to lose its CW status.

> I could create the canonical answer myself anyway, but I am not motivated to spend an hour or two doing so because I won't get any imaginary internet points for my work. This is built into the gaming philosophy of the system.

...Oh.  Erm...the altruist nature of CW posts does that.  It's a trade-off; do you want the imaginary points more than you want to share the knowledge?

> Documentation is in some sense replacing what community wiki originally intended. So the need for this question in particular (and many other questions in general) to be CW is not as critical as it was in the past.

I disagree.  Documentation has its scope and serves its particular master; community wikis have their scope and serve their particular master.  I sure wouldn't want to see (not that this already hasn't happened) a whole bunch of tacit and unexplained snippets in Documentation, nor would I want to in a CW, either.  You do raise an interesting point, though.

Comment: I would still like to know what the criteria is for removing CW status. See my update.